# How to do draw middle straight line in Opencv and calculate in to millimeter?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

how to draw a straight line in contour features in Opencv python and calculate in mm(millimeter). Im using also the cv2.line but it not giving me an accurate straight.

[Im just using a paint for this green line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFoVp.png)

```
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(6.jpg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower_blue = np.array([5, 25, 25])
    upper_blue = np.array([70, 255, 255])
    thresh = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)

    imask = thresh > 0
    green = np.zeros_like(frame, np.uint8)
    green[imask] = frame[imask]
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

    for c in cnts:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)

        # Draw rectangle
        cv2.rectangle(green, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36, 255, 12), 2)
        cv2.putText(green, "w={},h={}".format(w, h), (x, y - 10),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (36, 255, 12), 2)

        # Draw contours
        cv2.drawContours(green, [c], -1, (0, 255, 255), 3)
        break
```

Comment: The bottom endpoint seems pretty arbitrary. Do you want an automatic solution ? To get a measurement in mm, you simply need to calibrate (how many mm is a pixel).

Comment: Yes, Depends on the height. How to get the calculation for that? can you share some codes?

Comment: This is elementary arithmetic.

Comment: Yeah, I know but in coding since i'm new in python and can't get any reference sorry :)

Comment: `hmm = hpixel * refmm / refpixel`